# Determine the number of search results upon using different sets of separators (Excel)

Tags: search, indexing, excel-2010, separator

I would like to ask for your help with the formulation of a formula in Excel in order to  compare the total number of search results upon using different sets of separator characters.

As I have multiple columns with content, as in the example below, I thought it would be possible to Count the search results in some way and do this for each column separately ( I would actually prefer to treat each column separately).

```
                     A
1             L-516-S-221-S-223
2             H-140.STR3
3             ST0 XP 23-9
4             etc.......
```

Preferably, I would like to use a varying a set of separator characters in order to determine the impact on the number of search results based on this set of separator characters. Logically, with an increasing number of separators more results will be returned (depending on separators included in the cell values of course).

The set of characters that I would like to experiment with is: “-_ .,;: “

Hopefully this makes sense and someone is able to help me out. Thank you.

Kind regards,

P

Answer (score 0):

In your example `-` on its own will detect all three instances but for an overview you might construct a grid (say B1:H1 of your separators, including a space rather than an empty cell) and ColumnA each column in turn (maybe via links) then a formula in B2 such as:

```
=--ISNUMBER(FIND(B$1,$A2))
```

copied across to ColumnH and down to suit.

Alternative formula (for different question):

```
=IF(LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,B$1,""))>0,LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,B$1,""))+1,0)
```

Assumes, for example, no trailing spaces and separators are always separated. Results are not necessarily cumulative.

Comment: Thanks, but in a case of let's say 8,8,8 and looking at separator ',' it will return 2 if I'm correct? But the answer should be 3. Looking forward to your answer, thankyou.

Comment: I would like to count the number of strings that will exist with a certain set of separators. I do not want to count the type of separators in it. I hope this clarifies